# what to do after binning numerical feature?

Tags: machine-learning, binning, feature-engineering

I want to know what to do after I did the binning. For example, one of the feature is age. So my data is [11, 12, 35, 26].

Then I apply binning with size of 10:

bin,      name

[0, 10) --> 1

[10, 20) --> 2

[20, 30) -->3

[30, 40) --> 4

Then my data becomes [2, 2, 4, 3]. Now assume I want to put this data to a linear regression mode. Should I treat the [2, 2, 4, 3] as numerical feature? Or should I treat them as categorical feature, like do one-hot encoding first and then feed it to the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are building a linear model, then one hot encoding of those bins might be a better option, so that if there is any linear relationship with the target, the ohe will preserve it.

If you are building tree based models, like random forests, then you could use the [2, 2, 4, 3] as numerical feature, because these models are non-linear.

If building a regression model and not wanting to expand the feature space with ohe, you could treat the bins as a categorical variable, and encode that variable using mean / target encoding, or encoding with digits by following the target mean per bin.

More details about the last 2 procedures in [this article](https://trainindata.medium.com/feature-engineering-for-machine-learning-a-comprehensive-overview-a7ad04c896f8).

Disclaimer: I wrote the article.

Comment: I suggest you surround inline code with single back quotes, so that it is nicely styled.